# what does members indicate in django rest

Tags: django, curl, django-rest-framework

when i do a curl

`curl -H "Authorization: Token <token>" "http://localhost:8000/api/url"`

I get a response like this

`{"id":20,"team_name":"something","created_by":"joe","members":[{"member_name":"joe","status":"Self","member_id":1}]}%`

what does this members array indicate ?

Are they foreign key fields of this specific request

Comment: You're running it from localhost. Take a look at the source of the JSON response? I'd guess that the object relates to a member so `member_id` is likely a FK.

Comment: So my guess is right , the member array contain FK and elements, Thanks this helps a lot

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the members array holds the for foreign keys for your member names table.